# Setting import to run every 15 minutes

Tags: 7, feeds, cron

I am using Drupal 7.43, and I want to read my data from an external database every 15 minutes. My site is hosted on an Ubuntu server.

I am using Feeds importer with SQL parser. From import/feed_from_feed_db, all data is correctly imported; so, the importer runs correctly.

How can I set the feed importer to automatically run every 15 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

For periodic import select `As often as possible`.

[image]

Then use [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) and make the Feeds & Scheduler cron run every 15 minutes only, this way cron will not do other tasks that you don't need to do every 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) or triggers to make the feed importer run with the [cron task](https://www.drupal.org/node/23714)

Comment: Massoudi, this is a very short answer. Can you expand with more details on how to do this with any of the modules you mention?